# Coordinates using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working on python and openCV as a newbie, and I would like you guys to help me check why I'm getting a minor python error.

The main purpose of this code is to find the corners of a given image. This is not completely written by me, I'm looking into people's code to see what they did so I can leverage that to my advantage.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2


img = cv2.imread("sudoku_midterm/sudoku13.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours.sort(key=lambda c: np.min(c[:,:,1]))
j = 1

if len(contours) > 0:
    for i in range(0, len(contours)):
        size = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
        if 90 < size < 140:
            if j == 1:
                c1 = contours[i]
                j += 1
            elif j == 2:
                c2 = contours[i]
                j += 1
            elif j == 3:
                c3 = contours[i]
                j += 1
            elif j == 4:
                c4 = contours[i]
                break

Top = tuple(c1[c1[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
Right = tuple(c2[c2[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
Left = tuple(c3[c3[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
Bottom = tuple(c4[c4[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

cv2.circle(img, Top, 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(img, Right, 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(img, Left, 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(img, Bottom, 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The error I'm getting says:

```
name 'c1' is not defined
```

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: You are forgetting to give a variable (`c1`) a value before using it in another statement.

Comment: @eldesgraciado Thanks for your response, that's exactly my point. what value should c1, c2, c3. c4 be. I'm correcting the code and at the same time trying to understand what each variables are. Thanks

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the solution in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4` will only be defined if there is a contour with size between `90` and `140`. You need to have an alternative/default value for them. I would suggest setting them as arrays of `0.0` with the same shape as `contours[0]`, something like

```py
import numpy as np

# ...
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

c1 = np.zeros_like(contours[0])
c2 = np.zeros_like(contours[0])
c3 = np.zeros_like(contours[0])
c4 = np.zeros_like(contours[0])
# ...
```

Will prevent the error, although you may need to filter these out before drawing circles.